# Asp Mvc 5 Async/Await Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var service = new CoreServiceFactory().GetImpersonatingService();
    try
    {
        var data = new Impersonation()
        {
            ImpersonatingId = "dac733c3-01ad-447b-b0df-3a7c21fef90b",
            UserId = "dac733c3-01ad-447b-b0df-3a7c21fef90b"
        };
       var imp = await service.Add(data);

    }catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    return View();
}
```

Above is one of my controllers action method. And this works fine when the insertion is successful. This should fail if the data already exists in database(unique constraints). So when i intentionally try to make it fail(i manually add the same record in the db and then try to add it again via this action method) the action method goes into a loop or something, the exception is never thrown , chrome keeps me showing me the loading icon , looks like it went into some deadlock state. Can someone please help me understand why it goes into deadlock state when exception is thrown and how can i handle it?

### Below are the reference methods

### service.Add(data)

```
public async Task<Impersonation> Add(Impersonation t)
{
    if (ValidateData(t))
    {
        using (var uow = GetUnitOfWork())
        {
            var r = GetRepository(uow);
            var item = r.Add(t);
            try
            {
                var ret = await uow.Save();
                if (ret  > 0)
                {
                    return item;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ValidationException(null, "error");

    }

}
```

### uow.Save()

```
 public class BaseUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
        public DbContext _Context { get; private set; }


        public BaseUnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {

            this._Context = context;
        }

        public async Task<int> Save()
        {
            try
            {
                var ret =  await this._Context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return ret;
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of your Uow() class?  Also don't "throw ex;" as you lose the stack trace; just "throw;" instead.  While at it, follow the convention and rename your async methods to end ...Async() and we'll be able to better see what's going on.  Have you used SQL Server Profiler to see what's happening in the database?  Lastly we can't see your Repository.Add() method; are you sure the code is returning from that?  Add some Debug.WriteLine()s or similar to determine where the blocking is actually occurring

Comment: hi sellotape I just added the requested code..uow is really a barebone class..nothing special going on.

Comment: You are not really handling the errors anywhere.  What's the point of catching the exception and re-throwing it? If you really have no intention to do anything in case of errors, then just remove the try catch blocks. The code will throw anyways. Let us know what happens then.

Comment: and to answer your questions , repository.add() does work , as I mentioned the action method works perfectly when add is successful. but I added a record with the same data manually in the database so that the add method fails, because of primary key violation (UserId  is primary key) and when the adding is failed only then I loose control, and the action doesn't get the control back nor give me the errors. I tried this same code from a console app and it works even when the add fails

Comment: @FeryalBadili hi I didn't have any try catch blocks anywhere , and I was having same problem. then I though may be try catch and throwing error might help me to catch the error in the controller action method and gain control. and as u can see it didn't help either

Comment: How is your DbContext created?  Is it injected into BaseUnitOfWork, with a new instance created each time?  Is it at all possible another thread can hold a reference to the same DbContext instance?

Comment: @sellotape now this is wired..or may be I don't understand it right. I did what you said. instead of "throw ex" I just write "throw" and now when the service.add() failed the controller's index action catches that exception. can you please explain whats happening ??

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion: in uow.Save, log the error in the catch block and return zero (do not throw any exceptions).

```
public class BaseUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
        public DbContext _Context { get; private set; }


        public BaseUnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {

            this._Context = context;
        }

        public async Task<int> Save()
        {
            try
            {
                var ret =  await this._Context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return ret;
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // log the error here 
                return 0;
            }
          }
    }
```

I'm not sure if returning the null in the Add service is a good idea or not, you might need to handle that differently too.